# FileSync does not find my file

Tags: node.js, ssl

FileySync does not find files which are in a child folder (I also tried the same folder) of other modules which are found.

[image: Folder structure]

```
console.log __dirname
https = require('https')
fs = require('fs')
sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./config/ssl/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./config/ssl/server.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('./config/ssl/ca.crt'),
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}
secureServer = https.createServer(sslOptions,app).listen('3030', () ->
  console.log("Secure Express server listening on port 3030")
)

configDB = require('./config/database.js')(environment)
```

The database.js is found, the ssl files are not. The logged dirname:

```
---my project folder--/.tmp/serve
```

File Permissions:

config

```
-rw-r--r--  1 MasterG  staff   93 14 Apr 14:06 config.js
-rw-r--r--  1 MasterG  staff  526 14 Apr 14:06 database.js
drwxr-xr-x  6 MasterG  staff  204 14 Apr 13:51 ssl
```

ssl

```
-rw-r--r--  1 MasterG  staff  912 14 Apr 14:06 ca.crt
-rw-r--r--  1 MasterG  staff  963 14 Apr 14:06 ca.key
-rw-r--r--  1 MasterG  staff  924 14 Apr 14:06 server.crt
-rw-r--r--  1 MasterG  staff  887 14 Apr 14:06 server.key
```

Error:
unction strWrapper(err, written) {
                ^
Error:

```
ENOENT, no such file or directory './config/server.key'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:502:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:354:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MasterG/Desktop/PROJEKTE/gideon/.tmp/serve/server.js:25:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MasterG/Desktop/PROJEKTE/gideon/.tmp/serve/server.js:76:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/config/ssl/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/config/ssl/server.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/config/ssl/ca.crt'),
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}
```

To include __dirname did the trick, strange because in that tutorial it seemed to work without:
http://greengeckodesign.com/blog/2013/06/15/creating-an-ssl-certificate-for-node-dot-js/

Comment: `__dirname` returns the absolute path from where the node.js process is being executed. Your folder structure is different from the one used in the tutorial you linked. And the script in the tutorial is probably being executed from the same directory where the `ssl` is located.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros Wrong. `__dirname` is not the same as `cwd`, as you are suggesting. `__dirname` gives you the directory of which the current module is being run. `module` = `database.js` in this case. The confusion is that when you use `./` on `fs` functions, it implies `cwd`, but `./` in `require()` implies `__dirname`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @MiniGod You're right, I've confused the two things: `cmd()` with `__dirname`. And I think you should post your comment as an answer, because it better explains what's happening in this scenario.